# Strongloop - add fields to returned user model

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Any way to strongloop's /User/login responce can be extended by UserRoles  field?

By default strongloop return user object with "firstName, lastName, email, id and userName", i also need userRoles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [remote hook](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks) for the built-in login method.

in `user.js`

```
module.exports = User => {
  User.afterRemote('login', async (ctx, usr, next) => {
    let roleMaps = await User.app.models.RoleMapping.find({ where: { principalId: usr.userId } })
    let roleIds = roleMaps.map(roleMap => { return roleMap.roleId })
    let roles = await User.app.models.Role.find({ where: { id: { inq: roleIds } } })
    usr.roles = roles
    next()
  })
}
```

Note: I'm using ES6 and partially ES7 (async/await), but you can easily rewrite it to ES5.

Another option would be to create a relationship between your User and Role models and then use [include filter](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter) or [scopes](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Scopes).

Comment: Don't forget that you probably don't want to customize User, but rather your own model that extends User.